# Copy same elements from 2 ascending sorted linked lists to a new one

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that return a new list with elements contained in both two given ascending sorted lists, without any values repetition.
This code keeps given me `LeakSanitazire: detected memory leaks`, and i can't figure out what I'm missing.

**intersezione.c**

```
#include "intersezione.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

tlista intersezione(tlista lista1, tlista lista2){
  tlista head = NULL;
  tlista curr = NULL;
  tlista tail_lista2;
  while(lista1 != NULL){
    tail_lista2 = lista2;
    while(tail_lista2 != NULL){
      if(lista1->valore == tail_lista2->valore){
        if(head == NULL){
          head = (tlista)malloc(sizeof(struct cella));
          head->valore = lista1->valore;
          head->next = NULL;
          curr = head;
        } else if(lista1->valore != curr->valore){
          curr->next = (tlista)malloc(sizeof(struct cella));
          curr = curr->next;
          curr->valore = lista1->valore;
          curr->next = NULL;
        }   
      }
      tail_lista2 = tail_lista2->next;
    }
    lista1 = lista1->next;
  }
  return head;
}
```

[Here](https://repl.it/repls/ScrawnyHideousRotation) you can find the whole code.

Comment: Doesn’t this exhaust `lista2` on the first iteration of the outer loop and never reset it?

Comment: @Ry- not only that the function does not guarantee that there will be no repetitions in the intersection list. For example if your had `1 2 1 3 4` and `0 4 1 5 2 1` the intersection list (assuming the lists are searched correctly) would return `1 2 1 4` if im right. also please provde an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the provided code is not sufficient to detect your problem.

Comment: @Ry- Yeah that was silly. I edited my question.

Comment: @Yastanub I added a link to the whole code.

Comment: @FedericoGalfione please dont post links to code. Read the link i posted and then create a minimal compilable example which describes your problem.

Comment: @Yastanub Yeah I read it, but in the main I have to populate 2 linked lists and that's already too much for stackoverflow. I can't reproduce the same error with a simpler solution, cause at that point I wouldn't be sure that the memory leaks happen for the same reason. If you check the link you'll see that still a simple solution. Sorry if I can't be more comprehensive.

Comment: Is the data in both lists sorted?  If not, your code won't work well at all.  Also, depending on what `valore` is, a simple shallow copy/assignment here may not suffice to move it between lists.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yes, they always are and valore is an integer.

Comment: Please state that in the question  then so we don't have to ask :)

Comment: So, for fun, what if you just combined/concatenate the 2 lists, sorted them, then removed repeated entities instead of trying to do it on the fly?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yeah I could try, but I was also curious about why it give me memory leaks... I thought this function use memory in the right way, but obviously it's not like I thought.

Comment: `print_list(intersezione(lista1, lista2));` – printing a list doesn’t free it.

Comment: Why the free at the bottom of the function?  That seems strange.  I'd guess that is the source of the leak as it could be breaking the passed in lista2 chain up.

Comment: @Ry- I know but every single element inside the list is released when I call `free_all(lista1)` and `free_all(lista2)`

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yeah thanks. That free call was useless, I changed the question, but the error still happening.

Comment: @FedericoGalfione: `intersezione` creates an entirely new list. You only `free_all` `lista1` and `lista2`.

Comment: @Ry- That was right in front of me. Thank you very much, now it works as I expected.